# how to make a distinct graph plot based on one variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(14, FALSE, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 6), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0), c(0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 12, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11), c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13), c(0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13
), list(c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), names = character(0)), 
    list(name = c("Bestman", "Tera1", "Tera2", "Tera3", "Tera4", 
    "Tera5", "Tetra", "Brownie1", "Brownie2", "Brownie3", "Brownie4", 
    "Brownie5", "Brownie6", "Brownie7")), list()), <environment>), class = "igraph")
```

I can plot it like this

```
plot(df)
```

if I want to remove the label , I can do this

```
plot(df,vertex.label=NA)
```

but it removes it for all and I want to keep the core

I want to be able to plot it with ggplot , removing the label on each node but leave the main core label on , remove the line around the circles

Comment: you define `df` but plot `g`, is that just a naming problem in the sample data for this question?

Comment: What label do you want to remove?

Comment: @MrFlick when I plot it, I want to remove the labels from the members but keep the main core, does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dput is not directly reproducible (igraphs contain an environment which isn't included in a dput). The graph I can recover has two linked central nodes, each with several child nodes.

We can draw graphs with plentiful customization options using the `tidygraph` and `ggraph` packages:

```r
library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)
library(extrafont)

as_tbl_graph(g) %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  mutate(type = ifelse(name %in% c("Bestman", "Tetra"), "root", "branch")) %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(name == "Bestman" | grepl("Tera", name),
                      "Bestman", "Tera")) %>%
  ggraph(layout = "igraph", algorithm = "nicely") +
  geom_edge_link(width = 2, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(r = ifelse(type == "root", 0.4, 0.1), fill = group),
                   color = NA) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = ifelse(type == "root", name, "")), size = 5,
                 color = "gray40", family = "Roboto Condensed", fontface = 2) +
  theme_graph() +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel2", guide = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: can you somehow use different color for each central node and their members?

Comment: you make it very difficult to amend it, if I have more than 2 core, it is hard for me to amend `mutate(group = ifelse(name == "Bestman" | grepl("Tera", name),
                      "Bestman", "Tera"))` is there a way to make it more general or tell me what I should do if I have more Core names?

Comment: I get error when I add them like this `mutate(group = ifelse(name == "Bestman" | grepl("Tetra", name) | grepl("trueG", name)
                      | grepl("Carowner", name) | grepl("Bestwomen", name) ,
                      "Bestman", "Tetra","trueG","Carowner","Bestwomen" )) %>%`

Comment: @nik you need _some_ way of identifying the root nodes. It's difficult to generalise based on a single example, so I went for the simplest option given the information you provided. I'm sure there would be an algorithm that would work for your real data, but I would need to see your real data to write it. Perhaps include the data and the code you are using to create the graph in your question?

Comment: I asked another question with only that part, let me know if you have any idea